# Multiple table data get using with()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Here, is my eloquent

```
$contacts = Contact::where('property_id',$commercial->id)->where('property_type','commercial_lease')
                ->with('contact_log')
                ->with('user_name')
                ->with('contact_log.contact_log_name')
                ->get();
```

> `->with('contact_log')`
>   with this relationship...I got each and every data from that table using **->with('contact_log')**. But i want last inserted data via **with relationship**.

Others will remains same. But need to get only last data via this relation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply extra constraints on your **contact_log** relation in order to fetch only the last entry.

Replace

```
->with('contact_log')
```

with

```
->with('contact_log', function($query) {
  // order latest entries first
  $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
  // take only the first entry
  $query->take(1);
})
```